# Корпоративное Web приложение. С чего начать?

Tags: веб-программирование

Стоит задача сделать локальное корпоративное Web приложение для собственных нужд, т. е. конкретно для моей организации.

На данный момент задача небольшая, но планируется расширять функционал.

Сейчас необходимо:

1. Иметь возможность регистрироваться и авторизовываться на сайте.
2. Присваивать различные правами доступа пользователям
3. Добавлять отсканированную почтовую переписку в формате pdf или jpg (Хотя формат не особо важен)
4. Совместно с файлом вносить про него информацию - его реквизиты (от кого, куда, кому, когда и т.д.)
5. Иметь возможность удобной навигации, возможно в виде таблицы с фильтрами по этой почте.
6. Возможность выгрузить нужные файлы на локальный ПК.
7. Все действия, как писал выше, по уровню доступа.
8. Всё должно быть на открытом ПО, как Front-End так и Back-End.

Есть некоторые исходные. Уже имеется сервер в локальной сети, на котором есть PostgreSQL. Есть сервер с локальной Wiki. На нём, соответственно, Apache2 и MySQL.

В общих чертах я вижу решение этой задачи так:

1. Создать базу на сервере PostgreSQL c необходимой мне структурой.
   Которая будет хранить как отсканированные письма с их реквизитами,
   так и данные пользователей локальнного ресурса с их уровнем доступа.
2. Сделать страничку на PHP которая бы и работала с пользователями и
   базой данных.

Таким образом будет только база данных и к ней скрипты на каком-либо языке.

Так как не являюсь специалистом по Web разработке, а занимаюсь разработкой прикладного программного обеспечения для SCADA-систем, промышленных контроллеров и роботов, то вообще не принципиально с чего начать изучение.

После этого предисловия конкретные вопросы:

1. Нужны ли тут какие-либо фреймфорки типа Django?
2. На чём писать Back-end?
3. С чего начать?

Comment: Было бы не плохо еще знать сколько ресурсов (разработчиков) могут работать над проектом и какие технологии знают или хотели бы использовать. А так же определить какого "качества" должно быть приложение.

Comment: _"задача сделать локальное корпоративное Web приложение"_ -- а готовое не подходит? например, SharePoint.

Comment: Все зависит от возможностей разработчика(-ов), и от их квалификации или желанием изучать новые технологии. Ну и конечно от бюджета который могут дать на проект.
Проект можно написать как с использованием фреймворка так и без него. Ф-ка уже с коробки есть некоторые готовые решения (например: работа с БД, сессиями, возможно даже обработка файлов и.д.), для них есть много модулей которые расширяют его возможности. Если писать бекенд с нуля, то это займет много времени, и как показывает практика что их тяжело расширять другими программистами, но иногда проект стоит писать без ф-ка.

Comment: @WalterNuss, разработчик только я. Времени на разработку в свободное от основной работы (это разработка прикладного программного обеспечения для SCADA-систем и промышленных ПЛК и роботов) время. Приложение должно работать, требования в вопросе - 7 пунктов.

Comment: @Stack, 1 - не приветствуется лишнее платное программное обеспечение, тем более если оно не нужно. А SharePoint - огромная куча ненужного функционала конкретно для нас.

Comment: @SergiiChenakal, спасибо за полезную информацию для моего понимания вопроса.

Comment: Мой вопрос больше относится к пояснению в разделе [help/dont-ask]:

**Если мотивация задающего — «желание, чтобы мне объяснили что-либо», то, возможно, это хороший вопрос**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Фрэймворки облегчают работу, но и требуют изучения. Если ты не знаком с фрэймворком, то следует изначально подумать что будет сложнее - решить всё самому или пытаться выучить фрэймворк. Для данных задач можно было бы взять какой-нибудь ORM-Framework ну и может быть фраймоворк для разработки фронтэнда.
2. На чём писать бэкэнд вопрос на который нет однозначного ответа. Это зависит от того, что может команда. Я бы сделал бэкэнд полностью как веб-сервис (REST или SOAP). Таким образом твой фронтэнд стал бы независим от бэкэнда. Я любитель C# .NET и писать на нём веб-сервисы одно удовольствие. Если интересно то глянь Web API для RESTfull сервисов или WCF для SOAP сервисов.
3. Начать стоит с анализа требований и написания хотя бы набросков документов на тему какие функции хочет видеть заказчик (твой начальник например) и уговорить его подписаться под определенными требованиями. Это необходимо тебе в первую очередь, что бы обезопасить себя от обвинений в том, что ты всё не правильно понял. Это скорее всего встретится в штыки, но надо делать что бы потом не было мучительно больно. Если ты просто начнешь разработку не обговорив деталей того как и что должно по видению заказчика работать, то изменение функций на уже рабочем коде будет тебе стоить гораздо больше времени нежели просто переписать определение требования на бумаге. После этого я бы провёл анализ технологий которые лучше всего подходят для решения данных задач. Так же необходимо примерно расчитать время разработки умножить его на 2 и сообщить заказчику ;) После того как заказчик узнает как долго будет длиться разработка, еще может и передумать...

Comment: Ответ дал больше всего правильных мыслей по моему вопросу, заставил думать дальше. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Несмотря на крайне не однозначную постановку вопроса, всё же попытаюсь дать на него корректный ответ. Итак, по порядку.

1. Определяется постановкой задачи.
   Фреймворк, как и сам язык программирования всего лишь инструмент. В принципе можно обойтись и без них.
2. На любом серверном языке программирования, которым владеете и который поддерживает работу с необходимым Вам стеком технологий.
3. Начинать любой проект нужно с разработки технического задания. Даже если это проект для внутреннего пользования.

Comment: я-бы 3-й пункт сделал 1-ым и 2-м и третьим! Без ТЗ, особенно внутри компании, разработчику не выжить!Для составления правильного ТЗ надо определить основных акторов системы, провести с ними несколько совещаний, утвердить "7 красных параллельных прямых", заставить их все это подписать, забить на все на Х-времени, выслушать запоздалые правки и пожелания, понять - можно-ли их втиснуть в первоначальное задание, поругаться матом и только после этого приступать к реализации. Пока все это происходит - у вас возникнет понимание про инструменты и технологии!

Comment: @Борис, я ответил на вопросы в том порядке, в котором их задал автор. Если же это замечание в его адрес, было бы не плохо разместить комментарий в самом вопросе. Без обид.

Comment: какие обиды! На самом деле - это дополнение к вашему комментарию и, одновременно, ответ на его вопрос.

Comment: Тогда, мои извинения!